# How to execve() in common lisp (SBCL)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, execve

Whats is the best way to **[execve()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)** from lisp code in SBCL lisp implementation? Or maybe there is one good way working with all implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [external-program](https://github.com/sellout/external-program) that provides a portable way to run well... external programs in Common Lisp. It does the job for me, abstracting away the trivialities of the various interfaces provided by compilers is often a good choice, and in regard to the time `execve` will take the "performance" loss if there is any is really not relevant here.

If you really only target SBCL you have [sb-ext:run-program](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Running-external-programs) which is really a complicated execve. In my experience it still runs programs through /bin/sh and may do PATH lookup anyway so it might not end up being exactly an execve.

Comment: sb-ext:run-program doesn't go through /bin/sh.   [The source](http://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/src/code/run-program.lisp#l640) clearly says that "RUN-PROGRAM uses fork() and execve() to run a different program."  However, the manual page which you linked to does mention that "The sbcl implementation of run-program, like Perl and many other programs, but unlike the original cmu cl implementation, copies the Unix environment by default."  That might give the impression of running through /bin/sh sometimes, since some of the environment stuff would be there.

Comment: My bad it is external-program that uses /bin/env. [Source](https://github.com/sellout/external-program/blob/master/src/sbcl.lisp#L22)